# Online scheduling web app which allows customers to book appointments?

Tags: webapp-rec, calendar

I'm looking for an online scheduling system that allows my customers to book appointments/services online through one interface, and for myself and my team to manage all of the appointments (and ideally point of sale and CRM) through another interface. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[Doodle](http://doodle.com/) does the job for me, very straight-forward!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Tungle](http://tungle.com). Does what you're asking for and integrates well with a variety of mail and calendaring apps. Great support as well from @tunglerocks on Twitter. Has fully featured mobile apps etc. etc. Don't know what CRM tool you are using, but integrations exist for some, e.g. BatchBook.

Answer (score 0):

I found [When Is Good](http://whenisgood.net/) very easy and functional at the same time. You should give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Check also [Congregar](http://www.congregar.com).