# What are the alternatives to Facebook/Meetup for Event Planning

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm looking for an online webapp to manage event planning.

Here's the list of ideal requirements I'm looking for:

- To be able to propagate invitations to friends through either email and/or social network(s)
- Can export a specific event entry in vCalendar format
- Exposes an external API to retrieve a feed of events for a specific user/group
- Displays a link to an RSS/Atom feed of events for a specific user/group
- Displays a list of people who are invited and their status (attending/maybe/not)
- Has a description field for the event
- Has attached comments

Bonus:

- Includes a rating for specific events
- Includes a photo/video gallery or a way to link to an external gallery (Flickr/Youtube).
- OpenID login

*Note: To preserve cleanliness please only put one option per answer.*

Comment: similar question: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1981/what-online-scheduling-application-do-you-use

Comment: I feel this should be community wiki, if you are only having one 'option' per answer then the answers will be voted more on the merits of the service mentioned than the quality of the answer.

Comment: @Thomas Ok, done...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We always use [www.doodle.com](http://www.doodle.com) to manage our meetings. It's specially helpful to find a time/date slot that fits everybody. Give it a try.

I'm in their Outlook Connector Beta Program, with that, my outlook calendar is always in sync with it.

And here the individual points:
To be able to propagate invitations to friends through either email and/or social network(s)
=> via email
Can export a specific event entry in vCalendar format
=> yep
Exposes an external API to retrieve a feed of events for a specific user/group
=> Yes, they have an API, but couldn't find it now.
Displays a link to an RSS/Atom feed of events for a specific user/group
=> no idea, but there is a subscribe link 
Displays a list of people who are invited and their status (attending/maybe/not)
=> Absolutely
Has a description field for the event
=> Yes
Has attached comments
=> Yes

Comment: I have used Doodle a number of time, but I don't think it does all of the ideal requirements

Comment: +1 nice one. I've never heard of it. Could you please make the link an actual link and show how it measures up to the requirements?

Comment: could you please remove the comment and edit that into the answer so it's more readable?

Answer (score 1):

I use [eventbrite](http://www.eventbrite.com/) for managing meetings/events (mostly user groups) and have been very happy with it. It does everything in your ideal requirements except allow leaving comments.

Comment: +1 Do you have an account you could use to verify the requrements?

Comment: Nope. It doens;t allow attendees to leave comments. Everything else though.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [amiando](http://www.amiando.com/) which I've used when registering for a few events. (This is also what they used for StackOverflow DevDays.)
As a user (someone registering for the event) it was fine. Not sure on features but I've only seen it used for paid events.

Comment: +1 Nice, hopefully somebody else who has used it will come along and provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

I really like anyvite.com for invitations

Comment: +1 Cool, I think I have been invited to an event through this a very long time ago. Could you please make the link an actual link to the site and edit your answer to show anyvite measures up to the requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any mentions of [Evite](http://www.evite.com) yet, but it should handle at least a few of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

We use Fasterplan (http://www.fasterplan.com/), which is much like a simple WIKI. Widgets can be added to a billboard which is identified by a unique URL. Participants can be invited by simply forwarding that URL via E-Mail or Facebook or whatever, or they can be directly invited from the billboard (in this case Fasterplan sends the E-Mail, you can leave a personalized message). There are three kinds of widgets:

- formatted text widget: usually used to describe an event, make tables, etc.
- polls: others can propose new options or delete existing if the admin allows them to
- calendars: used to find a common date. again, new dates can be proposed or existing dates deleted if the admin gives permission to do so.

Participants can comment on each widget individually (which keeps the comments organized). The administrator (the one who creates the billboard and starts the organization) has to be signed-up, but any other participant can take part without being signed-up to Fasterplan, even without leaving his/her e-mail-address.