# Appointment Booking Software or Web Calendar?

Tags: calendar

We have an instrument which around 100 students will be using. The plan is to have online slot booking, where each student can book a slot depending on their convenience.

Now the requirements are:
1. Students can book the pre-defined slots.
2. Students can edit **only** their slots, like cancel the appointment etc.

The first requirement is fulfilled by many web based applications like Google Calendar. **The important issue is the 2nd requirement**, which is an absolute necessity since, we don't have one person to handle rescheduling or cancelling for such a large number of students.

Comment: Related: [Online scheduling web app which allows customers to book appointments?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1981)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [Doodle](http://www.doodle.com/) in the past and it's an excellent scheduling application. If you set it up so your students can only select one slot, it will work as a first come, first served basis where students can still edit their slots and switch to another available one. You can set the available times and the interface is lightweight and intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking [Bookeo](http://www.bookeo.com). I have been using it for my business and I love it.

You can set up the available time slots and students can book the available slot that suit them. Each student can also change or cancel their own booking.

Bookeo sends automatic email when students make a booking and can also send email reminders.